# Twig template with variable

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

My twig template has for loop, and I am trying to add a varable to it. How do I do this?

The ('var') needs to be the variable > content. + var + .related.buttons

```
{% include '@PleinCatalog/Theme/includes/themeCatergory.html.twig' with {'var':'something'} %}
{% for button in content.('var').related.buttons %}
      <a href="{{ button.url }}" class="btn btn-block btn-success">{{ button.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think it should work like this `{% for button in content[var].related.buttons %}`

Comment: Works like a charm.. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar for loop in my projects, where I include templates with some options.

Based on your example - it can be uses like that:

```
{% for button in content[var].related.buttons %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```